# For a ForeignKey field in a form, how do you display a widget other than a Select menu?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a modelchoicefield that has too many valid options to really show in a  menu.  How can I tell Django forms to use another widget that won't take up as much space rendering?

I want to use a HiddenField and I have another widget on the screen taht will populate it. If the hiddenfield has no value I keep getting form validation errors on it even though it is marked as required=false

Comment: What other widget would you like to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is use the `widget` parameter of the form field definition...

But the question really is [what other widget](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#ref-forms-widgets) would you like to use?

There are [some](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/233/) [examples](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/YUI-Django-AutoComplete) of autocomplete widgets. But nothing out of the box.

Comment: For AutoComplete widgets, take a look at http://jannisleidel.com/2008/11/autocomplete-form-widget-foreignkey-model-fields/

Comment: I want to use a HiddenField and I have another widget on the screen taht will populate it.  If the hiddenfield has no value I keep getting form validation errors on it even though it is marked as required=false.

Comment: Can you post your form and Model?